# Understanding Texas legislative process

Tags: united-states, senate, legislative-process, state-legislatures, texas

If a Bill passes the Senate in Texas, does that mean it becomes law as the next step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before a Bill can become law, it must be passed both by the House of Representatives and the Senate.  It can originate in either chamber (except for revenue bills, which must originate from the House), and both chambers have the power to reject a law.

After the Bill passes both chambers, the Governor must approve or veto the Bill.  If he approves, then it becomes law; if he vetoes, then the veto can be overridden by two-thirds of both houses.

In Texas, under Article III, Section 39 of the [state Constitution](https://tlc.texas.gov/docs/legref/TxConst.pdf), laws cannot come into force for 90 days after it has been passed, unless two-thirds of each chamber vote otherwise.